# Please explain App Engine Instances parameters

Tags: google-app-engine, multiple-instances

In App Engine Dashboard-> In Combobox Summmary -> I choose Instances: there are these values:created, active.

I dont understand what does created Instances mean, active Instances mean.

Is created Instances idle Instances?

Is active Instances dynamic Instances?

Why created Instances is 3 but active Instances is 1, then my system fail.

Warning:
''While handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.''

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Created instances are the ones your application started in a given situation, not necessarily serving, and can also be idle. Instances are created depending on the [instance scaling type](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed?hl=es#instance_scaling) you specified in your app.yaml.

Active instances are those instances that are serving traffic or have served traffic at a given timeframe.

Here's [How Instances are Managed in App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed) for detailed explanation about GAE instances.

The warning you received is usually due to the available instance exceeds the maximum memory for its configured [instance_class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements)  . You might need to specify higher instance class or use [max_concurrent_requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#max_concurrent_requests) to optimize your instances and properly handle requests.

You could also configure maximum and minimum number of instances in your [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements) depending on how much traffic you would like your application to handle.